# Not displaying Hidden Fields in view source

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, security

How to prevent user from showing hidden fields on a page when a user clicks view source.
As I want to make my application more secure. I want the view source page not to display the hidden fields which I am passing on my POST method.
Also, i want to hide the javascipt/jquery and css code on the page.

In nutshell, i don't want the user to see any irrelevant data(for user). 
Any suggestions.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do that, but what is the security issue you are talking about?

Comment: Best to avoid storing sensitive information anywhere anything but your server has access to it. If you must, you must encrypt it. Anything short of this is a compromise that someone will eventually exploit

Answer (score 3):

First thing : no html code or css code can be hided. If you will open fir bug or some other thing it can be seen easily.

View source shows the code which are actually written in html page (ie: elements which are not added dynamically.)

So if you just don't want not to show it on view source you can add that hidden field dynamically using JavaScript. But event though it is visible by firebug.

If that information is too secure just don't add it on hidden field.

Little better way : 
save it on a global javascript object like :

```
var hiddenValue={
'hidden1':"some value",
'hidden2':"some value2"
}
```

//storing in global variable give you flexibility to change it later as in hidden field.

if you want to post this values in form. Do it using javascript.
like

```
//a jquery example

    function submitForm(){
    var formObj=$('#form');
    formObj.append('<input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="'+hiddenValue.hidden1+'" /><input type="hidden" name="hidden2" value="'+hiddenValue.hidden2+'" />').submit();
    }
```

But remember there is always a way to see front end code. Only you can do is to make it complex to read.

Comment: But it also visible. i change the value of javascript variables through console .

Answer (score 0):

not too much you can do other than disabling right click. But they can still inspect using firebug and other inspectors

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this because there is always a way to view the source code.

What you can do, is keep all the information you want to pass along in an encrypted cookies or session variables.

As for security, if you have stuff displayed in HTML/Javascript that should secured, I highly suggest you rethink your approach.

Remember that HTML is the rendered code that the browser will output so hiding parts of it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) server side scripting for java script.
and rather then using hidden fields try to use java script cache .

when JavaScript is secured then your  java scripting will also be secure rather than hidden fields

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should

> put the values in a cookie
>
> encrypt the cookie and send it to the client

on reception of the request

> decrypt the cookie and read the values

or if the data is sensitive use sessions